# How to populate django form , based on two ModelForm

Tags: django, python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hde3U.png)I want my app users to be able to edit two forms using one html page , were these two forms will be populated with initial data from two related models,but i am not able to accomplish this result yet,

## models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_vendor = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Vendor(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User)
  phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

## forms.py

```
class VendorProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Vendor
        fields = ['phone',]


class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email']
```

## views.py

```
def Edit_Vendor_Profile(request, pk):
    # querying the custom User model .
    user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    vendor = Vendor.objects.get(user_id=user.id)

    if request.method == "POST":
        vendor_form = VendorProfileForm(request.POST,request.FILES,                                                    
                                                     instance=vendor)
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=user)

        if vendor_form.is_valid() and user_form.is_valid():
            vendor_form.save()
            user_form.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    else:
        vendor_form = VendorProfileForm(request.POST,request.FILES,                                                 
                                                     instance=vendor)
        user_form = UserForm(instance=user)

        return render(request, "accounts/update.html", {'vendor_form':vendor_form, 'user_form':user_form})
```

so the problem is that fields of user model are being populated fine but fields from Vendor model are not.so what that i am doing wrong,
thank you very much in advanced .

I edited my views.py, according to Mr, LeLouch's answer, witch is very close but still am not getting all of my form fields populated correctly .

note:i have an image field and its data is populated correctly !!

Comment: Model and instance must match. If you have Vendor ModelForm then instance must be Vendor, not User.

Comment: thanks you Borut, you are right , i tried (instance=user.vendor), but the fields are still not initialized correctly.

Comment: user.vendor is still User instance.

Comment: i had the same problem a couple of days ago and i solved it..just check my answer

Comment: Vendor exists already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Vendor(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User)
  phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)


#using this to create a vendor model every time a user is created
def create_vendor(sender, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs["instance"]
    if kwargs["created"]:
        vendor = Vendor(user=user)
        vendor.save()
post_save.connect(vendor, sender=User)


def Edit_Vendor_Profile(request, pk):
        # querying the custom User model .
        user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
        vendor = Vendor.objects.get(id= user.id)
        user_form = UserForm(instance=user)
        vndor_form = Vendor(instance=vendor)
        if request.method == "POST":
            vendor_form = VendorProfileForm(request.POST,request.FILES, 
                                                            instance=vendor)
            user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=user)

            if user_form.is_valid():
                created_user = user.save() (commit=False)
                vendor_form = VendorProfileForm(request.POST,request.FILES, 
                                                            instance=created_user)
                if vendor_form.is_valid():
                    created_user.save()
                    vendor_form.save()

                return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
        else:
            vendor_form = VendorProfileForm()
            user_form = UserForm()

            return render(request, "accounts/update.html", {'vendor_form':vendor_form, 'user_form':user_form})
```

Comment: Thank you Mr LeLouch, but i am still getting an empty form,

Comment: i added screenshot, for better understanding to my problem .

Comment: My bad, i assumed your vendor instance is created and the instance id is the same as the user id since this is how i used to do it . the reason the fields are not populated in your case because the instance of the vendor doesn't exist in the first place. to check that. you have to add the Vendor model to the admin first (go to your admin.py and add the following admin.site.register(Vendor) if you have done that go to admin panel and check if u have any Vendor Objects to begin with.

Comment: i have more than 10 vendors in the admin page, and all the fields have values,

Comment: probably because the userid doesn't match the vendor id just tried it  in a new venv using the following model view and form and it works fine

Comment: finally i got it working, and my mistake was, after "Else" block i just needed to pass only vendor instance without request.POST, request.Files. like so (        vendor_form = VendorProfileForm(instance=vendor)
        user_form = UserForm(instance=user)   )

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
def Edit_Vendor_Profile(request, pk):
    # querying the custom User model .
    user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)

    if request.method == "POST":
        vendor_form = VendorProfileForm(request.POST,request.FILES, 
                                                        instance=user.vendor)
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=user)

        if vendor_form.is_valid() and user_form.is_valid():
            vendor_form.save()
            user_form.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    else:
        vendor_form = VendorProfileForm(instance=user.vendor)
        user_form = UserForm(instance=user)

        return render(request, "accounts/update.html", {'vendor_form':vendor_form, 'user_form':user_form})
```

Comment: thank you Mr, Sascha , but i am still getting an empty vendor form,except the file fields(they are populated) , and i don't know why

Comment: i added screenshot, for better understanding to my problem.

Comment: I ask again Vendor already exists. Verndor doesn't have to be created, right?

Comment: yes , vendor exists, and all of my fields have values saved in the database, and when i go to the admin page i find all of my vendors with full details .